# How can i create sitemap with changing ids?

Tags: seo, sitemap, google-search, search-engine-bots

i developed one paged site ( mainly only the index) and i don't know actually how to optimize it seo friendly. For example, i have a open book library and that books are open like "index#LoTR" "index#BookId" . Google can't dedect "https://example.com/index#Lord-of-the-rings" . I am also changing meta tags according to containing id in url. So in search engines, i am only visible with my main page not with my products.

I tried to create sitemap.xml but i couldn't find exact solutions for my problem.

```
   <url>

      <loc>http://www.example.com/index#YOUR_ID</loc>

      <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>

   </url>
```

i found some way to do like upper code but how can i make it changeable?

For example in **.htaccess**:
`RewriteRule ^index#(.*)$ http://www.example.com/index.php#$1 [L,QSA]`
we can implay that after index.php#... changeable but how can we do this in sitemap.xml or for search bots ways.

I hope you understand me bcz i'm not a native speaker thnx :)

Comment: not solved yet.